# What voting method are you using?

Tags: discussion, election

Since the election is for Pro Webmaster, I'm asking it here.

How does the voting take place?

- [First past the post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-past-the-post)
- [Alternative Transferable Vote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_Transferable_Vote)
- [Single Transferable Vote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote)

Not that it really matters, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [primary](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=primary) and [election](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=election) tabs for those phases, the sidebar has the info you are looking for.

**Primary:**

> After 4 days, the top 10 candidates based on primary vote score proceed onward to the election phase.

**Election:**

> After 4 days, the final voting results will be freely downloadable from this page forever, and we will calculate the 3 winners using OpenSTV with the Meek STV method.